# Glare node not working with a gradient emission material, how can I fix this?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, compositing-nodes, emission, glare

I've been working on a project using the glare node in the compositing tab and so far experimenting with the emission material by itself has been fine, but as soon as I added a gradient node to the material I got problems with my render with the bloom effect from the glare node not fully working on certain areas of the shapes.

[image: glare not working render]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem with the final render? or if not does anyone know another way to get a similar neon bloom effect in cycles? my node setup for the materials and compositing is bellow:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of those colors are a bit darker than others. Reducing the glare threshold should work, or alternatively you could increase the emission strength on the materials.